# Clear button color on text field

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

How do you change the clear button color of a UITextField?

Comment: You need to subclass UITextField.

Comment: subclass UITextField and do what?

Comment: I answered this question for you a long time ago and never received any feedback on whether it helped or not.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use `rightView` and `rightViewMode`.  Use a button and add an image that is a red clear button.  Then add your target and perform your logic.

`rightViewRectForBounds` will also return the size of the button for the `rightView`.